# Indy TIdHTTPServer OnCommandGet javascript in html not executing

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, indy, httpserver

I have a `TIdHTTPServer` that sends javascript code in an html file to the browser with tag `<script language="javascript">` in the `<head>` tag. I don't have access to the html file so I cannot change it's content. I use `HTTPServerCommandGet` to send the contents of this file to the browser like this :

```
procedure TMainForm.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  responseMemoryStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  responseMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
    AResponseInfo.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8';
    AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
    responseMemoryStream.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'index.html');
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    TMemoryStream(AResponseInfo.ContentStream).LoadFromStream(responseMemoryStream);
  finally
    responseMemoryStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I then make a `GET` command from an internet browser it sometimes loads the javascript, but sometimes it doesn't - when I use **Firefox** there are no problems, but when I use **Chrome** or **IE** the javascript never executes. Is there a way to force the execution of the javascript code somehow with the `AResponseInfo` variable or there is nothing I can do to fix this ?

This is what part of the `index.html` looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta  charset=utf8 />
    <title>My title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        var map;
        var flag_for_map_massage = 0;
        var map_marker = 0;
        function initmap()
        {
            var html;
            var map_divtxt = "<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width:200px;height:150px;\" ></div>";
            document.getElementById("google_map").innerHTML = map_divtxt;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(100.12345, 200.12345);

            var options = {
                zoom: 17,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

            var html = "<table>" +
                    "<tr><td>GMBH Address</td> </tr>";

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: html
            });
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(100.12345, 200.12345),
                map: map1

            });
            //     infowindow.open(map1, marker1);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function() {
                infowindow.open(map1, marker1);
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initmap();">  
  <div class="entry">
    <div id="google_map">
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just seen that this piece of code ``var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(100.12345, 200.12345);`` cannot be executed (and everything afterwards) when it's send in the ``OnCommandGet``, but if I open the file itself with a browser - it executes ok.

Comment: @whosrdaddy - nowhere - apparently they get loaded automatically somehow (when I inspect element in the browser after loading the file locally I see 3 Google Maps API ``<script>`` tags in the ``<head>`` tag) and, like I said, I cannot edit the ``index.html`` file

Comment: It seems that I have deleted unintentionally from the ``index.html`` part I've shown in order to make the content as small as possible : this is what I have before the ``javascript`` code : ``<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>``, and it worked only in ``Firefox`` - ``IE`` and ``Chrome`` failed to load the map.

Comment: I've removed the ``.css`` calling

Comment: If you use the developer tools in your browser, can you see whether those javascript files are loaded (Network tab) and executed without errors (Console tab)?

Comment: P.S: I removed my comments because they do not have any value anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your server can do is deliver the HTML to the browser, nothing more.  It is browser's responsibility to process the HTML, retrieve external resources, execute scripts, etc.  If the browser is not functioning correctly, then chances are the HTML/script has errors in it to begin with.  That has nothing to do with your server (unless you are corrupting the data you are sending).

With that said, you do not need to use two streams in your `OnCommandGet` code, that is overkill.  One stream is enough.  Also, `utf-8` is not a valid `ContentEncoding` value, so you need to remove that.

Try this:

```
procedure TMainForm.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  TMemoryStream(AResponseInfo.ContentStream).LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'index.html');
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure TMainForm.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TIdReadFileExclusiveStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'index.html');
end;
```

And, of course, make sure you are paying attention to the `ARequestInfo.Document` property and only serving `index.html` if the browser is actually requesting `index.html` and not some other file on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Indy10's IdCustomHTTPServer.pas has a bug.

Setting AResponseInfo.Charset value doesn't work.
Because the following line (Line 2141 in Pas file) overrides the Charset variable.

```
  if ContentType = '' then begin
    if (ContentText <> '') or (Assigned(ContentStream)) then begin
      ContentType := 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'; {Do not Localize}
```

In order to correct, add two files below (copy from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\source\Indy10\Core" to your Project directory then add to your Project):

IdCustomHTTP.pas

IdCompilerDefines.inc

modify line 2141 as

```
ContentType := 'text/html; charset='+Charset;
```

;-)